# Resource in MSVC++ 2013

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I want to access my resource as a `char*` or vector or a FILE. I tried the below and I got null. I don't understand why. The first parameter is [optional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648043%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the last I took from the documentation page. RT_RCDATA seems to be what I want. IDK why I am getting null

```
HRSRC rc = FindResourceEx(0, RT_RCDATA, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MyResource), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL));
```

I get the error 1813. I have a single executable with no dlls. The resource is in the executable

Comment: In which binary the resource is located? NULL implies the executable

Comment: Use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx to understand why it's failing

Comment: @MarcoA.: Error 1813 its not found. Someone suggest using 10. I looked up RT_RCDATA which is what I am using and its... 10. IDK whats going on

Comment: @acidzombie24 What is the resource *type* in your .rc file?. The .rc line should be of the form `ID Type filepath`. What is the string for the *type* ?

Comment: @WhozCraig: I'm not sure here is my rc file http://pastebin.com/czJQ7bPc Does that mean I should use `MAKEINTRESOURCE("v2")`? It didnt work either. I still get 1813 as my lasterror

Comment: @acidzombie24 posted what I hope is the proper solution for you for `FindResource`. Yeah, that was exactly what I meant, and thanks for the link. The relevant line(s) in your resource script and `resource.h` file should be included as part of your question, btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering (I hope) this question and  [your prior question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611539/load-binary-resource-in-visual-c), This answer applies to `FindResource`, though you can adapt to `FindResourceEx`

The parameters to `FindResource` are module-to-search, id, and type.

- The first is the instance handle who'd resource table to search. You can use `NULL` for the running process, Otherwise this is in a DLL you need to save off your instance handle from DllMain, usually in a global `ghInst`, and use that for your search target.
- The second should be your resource id. If you're using macro ids such as from a `resource.h` header, the id must be wrapped with `MAKEINTRESOURCE(id)`. Otherwise its the same string (as a string) you used for your resource id.
- The third is the resource *type*. When you declared your custom resource you gave it a type in your resource script (something like MYRES; Ex: I use XML for xml files, for example). The `type` parameter is that value as a string.

Therefore, finding the custom resource of id `MY_ID` (taken from an included `resource.h` id file) of type `MYDATA` in the current processes resource table would be:

```
HRSRC hRes = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(MY_ID), _T("MYDATA"));
```

Similarly, loading the same resource from a DLL resource table, assuming you saved the instance handle of the DLL to some global `ghInst` in the `PROCESS_ATTACH` of your `DllMain`, is:

```
HRSRC hRes = FindResource(ghInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(MY_ID), _T("MYDATA"));
```

---

**Missing ID**

It is not uncommon to "forget" to properly declare the identifier used for the resource in a .h file that is included in the resource script *and* C/C++ code, but the resource script will happily still compile. If the following is in your resource script

```
MY_ID MYDATA "filename.bin"
```

and `MY_ID` is **not** defined via macro as a numeric id and included in your resource script, this will "name" a resource called `"MY_ID"` (note its a *string*) in the output resource table. Worse, if the id-defining-macro **is** properly included in the C/C++ code trying to load this thing, then this:

```
HRSRC hRes = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(MY_ID), _T("MYDATA"));
```

will compile, since the C/C++ code has `MY_ID` properly available, but the resulting id is *not* the same as the one used in the resource file, which was a string name. Thus the load will fail. A sure sign this happened is if this fails:

```
HRSRC hRes = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(MY_ID), _T("MYDATA"));
```

but this works:

```
HRSRC hRes = FindResource(NULL, _T("MY_ID"), _T("MYDATA"));
```

If you find this is the case, make sure your .rc file *and* your C/C++ code are using the same macro for your resource identifier. It can't just be the same "name". It has to be the same *macro*. If the macro is not available to the resource compiler it will use the name as a string, which is usually *not* what you want.

Best of luck.

Comment: @acidzombie24 Glad it helped. I'm woefully aware of the anorexic list of examples on doing this in current documentation. Ironically it was better amplified a *long* time ago in the 3.0/3.1/95 days.

Comment: In the 3m since I posted I figured out how to do the rest of the code which was to access the raw data and grab the size of the resource. Its ridiculous how terrible the documentation and google has been for this function. I use to have a win32.hlp file or something like that filename. Sadly .hlp no longer works since vista

Comment: Note: You *can* use `RT_RCDATA` etc if properly set up, I just find naming my resource types easier. Each has its benefits, but I do this so rarely I opt for brain-dead, (when it comes to me, the less thinking-required the better).

Answer (score 2):

2 things:

- `MAKEINTRESOURCE(RT_RCDATA)` should be `RT_RCDATA` according to the docs.
- The first parameter is the handle to the binary (DLL/exe) holding the resource, NULL implies the executable.

Comment: Ah, I made the change and I still get 1813 which is resource not found. I have a single executable and the resource is in it. Its a console app and I'm not sure how to get the instance but anyways the resource is the executable